# Can not join room in socket.io from inside promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, socket.io

I am trying to make a socket join a room from inside a `.then()` but it's not working. I know everything else is correct in the code because after moving it (the join) outside of the `.then()` and into a sync function it works. How can I make it work this way?

```
client.query('SELECT x FROM y WHERE f= $1;', ["example"])
.then((results) => {
    socket.join('test');// join room
    //more code that works properly...
})
```

Comment: Can you further elaborate what's not working?

Comment: @Evert Well what is not working is that the socket does not join the room.  The way im pretty sure this is the issue is because i have a function in which i emit a message. When i do `socket.join();` outside of the `.then()` it works and the message is being sent. When the `.join` is inside the `.then()` no emitting happens at all (nothing reaches the client).

Comment: Do you have `.catch` clauses for all your promise chains?

Comment: yes and it all works fine, the only bit that fails is the `socket.join()`

Answer (score 0):

You can try with async await for the socket.io connection.

Comment: Not sure if thats going to work because as far as i know in this context async/wait is not different to how promises work. I would also very much prefer to do it with promises